# Is there a standard to sign and verify node.js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, code-signing

I have a certificate for code signing and I want to know if is there a standard way to sign and verify a nodejs/javascript code? Maybe using OpenSSL or other tools?

Unlike binaries, the nodejs/javascript code has multiples files and that makes it more complex to use some utilities to sign software.

Answer (score 2):

If you upload JavaScript to a web server, you "sign" it by serving it with a TLS certificate. You can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get one for free.

If you're trying to, essentially credit yourself, adding a license alongside your JavaScript files is how you would "sign" it.

Since JavaScript is not a binary format itself, there's no way to sign it with a Code Signing Certificate. However, Node.js **is** a signed binary that is used to execute your code.

If you're trying to sign a binary compiled from JavaScript with a tool like [`pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg), use a Code Signing Certificate.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to use a headerless zip to reproduce the same zip with the same code and sing that zip and reproduce it. But I don't think if there is a standard way to do that

Answer (score -1):

## Warning

i don't think this has ever been done before or this is a standard way of doing this but i do have a plan/idea

### Steps

- 1 have a source map of all the files in project [with or without excluding stuff like node_modules and .env]
- 2 convert each file to a hash [which doesn't matter best to pick the one with the most text to hash possible]
- 3 add all the hash to a file like the source map but instead of the file path it would a bunch of hash [filename:hash; something like json]
- 4 then using your public key to encrypt that file and hash that file lets call it "CSIGN"

### Verification

do the same steps again save it in the file "VSIGN" and then check if "VSIGN"  and "CSIGN" are the

## Disclaimer

this has a lot of issues like you might need to implement some solution for big files and then u will have to save everyone's public key somewhere and a lot more

but if your ready and you do need help you could contact me, check my bio